# Why does React app fail to start when running in container, but very same code runs OK when started from terminal?

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile

I learn React and try to run an app. When I start the app in terminal, it goes nice and works as expected, but when I do the very same thing in container it fails. Here are the details:

```
root@b8457ff69aac:/app# node -v
v16.17.0
root@b8457ff69aac:/app# npm -v
8.15.0
```

The error:

```
root@b8457ff69aac:/app# npm start server

> voting_app@1.1.0 start
> npm run server


> voting_app@1.1.0 server
> live-server public --host=localhost --port=9001 --middleware=./disable-browser-cache.js

(node:134) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Serving "public" at http://localhost:9001 (http://127.0.0.1:9001)
/app/node_modules/opn/index.js:82
                    reject(new Error('Exited with code ' + code));
                           ^

Error: Exited with code 3
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/opn/index.js:82:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:451:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:757:14)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.17.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 9001
# for sake of debug
CMD [ "sleep" , "infinity" ]
```

And running it:

```bash
docker run -p 9001:9001 vote-app:test2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/app/node_modules/opn/index.js:82
     reject(new Error('Exited with code ' + code));
```

hints that [the `opn` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opn) is failing. That module is used to op(e)n a browser, which can't happen in a container.

Add `--no-browser` to your `live-server` command line to prevent it trying to open a browser.

Furthermore, you'll need `--host=0.0.0.0` instead of `--host=localhost` so the exposed port can work from within the container.

As an aside, you'll probably also want to see if you can update your version of `live-server` to get rid of that deprecation warning.

Comment: wow! thank you so much. It now runs just fine!